# UICollectionView Tutorial Request

Tags: ios6, uistoryboardsegue, uicollectionview

Looking for a tutorial or help doing the following

Keep it as an iPad App and using Storyboards. I need a (this is my Main) viewController (No Detail or Navigation View) with a popover that displays a UiCollectionView (and the Cells) of images). I want a ContainerView inside my main). The Container displays a default imageView and selection from the CollectionView, changes the Image in the Container. Also, the segue from the CollectionView Cell to the Container's Imageneeds to be of Custom Segue Type.

Remember, it's for an IPad, with Storyboard. No detail or Navigation Controller.

How's that for a Tutorial. There is nothing else like it right now and I could sure use the help.

Doug

Answer (score 0):

This one appears pretty good.. The code is also sitting on github..

Tutorial: http://maniacdev.com/2012/09/tutorial-how-to-create-an-ios-6-uicollectionview-using-storyboards/

Source: https://github.com/AshFurrow/UICollectionViewExample

Answer (score 0):

Yet another [UICollectionView tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12)